# Wifi not working after a few minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm using a few MacBooks and iPads connected to a router via WiFi. The problem is that a few minutes after they connect via WiFi the connection stops working. This happens on all devices. I went into the router settings by connecting via cable and everything seems in order.

Connecting a laptop via cable to the router I can use internet as normal, the problem is only with WiFi. What can be the problem here?

Here are the connected clients

```
    Connected Clients   
 MAC Address     Idle(s)     RSSI(dBm)   IP Addr     Host Name  Mode    Speed (kbps)
14:10:9F:F3:48:D6   1   -36 192.168.0.5 Jeans-Air   n   78000
14:99:E2:C6:41:10   1   -36 192.168.0.8 JeanGaleasiPad  n   24000
```

Here's the router event log

```
 Mon Dec 30 04:12:30 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 1 (Side-Band Channel:N/A)... 
 Mon Dec 30 04:12:25 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 1 (Side-Band Channel:5) -... 
 Mon Dec 30 02:17:56 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 40 (Side-Band Channel:36)... 
 Mon Dec 30 02:16:04 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 11 (Side-Band Channel:7) ... 
 Mon Dec 30 01:59:26 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 6 (Side-Band Channel:N/A)... 
 Mon Dec 30 01:59:22 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 6 (Side-Band Channel:2) -... 
 Sun Dec 29 23:27:51 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 1 (Side-Band Channel:N/A)... 
 Sun Dec 29 23:27:49 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 11 (Side-Band Channel:N/A... 
 Sun Dec 29 14:32:55 2013    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - ... 
 Sat Dec 28 13:08:19 2013    Error (4)   DHCP REBIND WARNING - Field invalid in response ;CM-MAC=1c:3e... 
 Fri Dec 27 18:10:19 2013    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - ... 
 Fri Dec 27 16:08:55 2013    Error (4)   Map Request Retry Timeout;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1:6b:84;CMTS-MAC=0... 
 Thu Dec 26 21:08:53 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 11 (Side-Band Channel:7) ... 
 Thu Dec 26 20:43:50 2013    Notice (6)      WiFi Interface [wl0] set to Channel 11 (Side-Band Channel:N/A... 
 Tue Dec 24 12:45:03 2013    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - ... 
 Tue Dec 24 04:55:52 2013    Error (4)   Map Request Retry Timeout;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1:6b:84;CMTS-MAC=0... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:32:00 2013    Notice (6)      TLV-11 - unrecognized OID;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1:6b:84;CMTS-MAC=0... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:32:00 2013    Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV Type: 17.9;CM-MAC=1c:3e:... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:32:00 2013    Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV Type: 17.8;CM-MAC=1c:3e:... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:32:00 2013    Warning (5)     DHCP WARNING - Non-critical field invalid in response ;CM-MAC... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:32:02 2013    Notice (6)      Honoring MDD; IP provisioning mode = IPv4 
 Mon Dec 23 18:31:10 2013    Critical (3)    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:28:57 2013    Critical (3)    Received Response to Broadcast Maintenance Request, But no Un... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:28:25 2013    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - ... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:17:48 2013    Notice (6)      TLV-11 - unrecognized OID;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1:6b:84;CMTS-MAC=0... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:17:48 2013    Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV Type: 17.9;CM-MAC=1c:3e:... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:17:48 2013    Error (4)   Missing BP Configuration Setting TLV Type: 17.8;CM-MAC=1c:3e:... 
 Mon Dec 23 12:17:48 2013    Warning (5)     DHCP WARNING - Non-critical field invalid in response ;CM-MAC... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:17:48 2013    Notice (6)      Honoring MDD; IP provisioning mode = IPv4 
 Mon Dec 23 18:16:58 2013    Critical (3)    No Ranging Response received - T3 time-out;CM-MAC=1c:3e:84:f1... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:16:15 2013    Critical (3)    Received Response to Broadcast Maintenance Request, But no Un... 
 Mon Dec 23 18:15:43 2013    Critical (3)    Started Unicast Maintenance Ranging - No Response received - ...
```

Comment: Does your router have a log file of some sort?

Comment: Could you let us know the make and model of the router?

Comment: Its a Ubee 
Information
MSO 
Standard Specification Compliant DOCSIS 3.0
Hardware Version 3.14.1
Software Version 9.32.1004
Cable Modem MAC Address 1c:3e:84:f1:6b:84
Cable Modem Serial Number C713L27500022
CM certificate Installed